# Extracting data using regex - Optional capturing group causing trouble

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this test string, which I want to extract data from using Regex:

"-> **Single-row index lookup on  using <auto_distinct_key> (actor_id=actor.actor_id)** *(cost=**901.66** rows=**5478**)* (actual time=**0.001..0.001** rows=**0** loops=**200**)"

The six fields of data that I want to extract are written in bold. The segment that is written in italic is the optional part of the statement.

This is the pattern which I have arrived at thus far:

`-> (.+) (\(cost=([\d\.]+) rows=(\d+)\))? \(actual time=([\d\.]+) rows=(\d+) loops=(\d+)\)`

This gives me six groups with all the data I want. However, when I omit the optional part of the string it does not match at all. I suspected this was due to superfluous whitespaces, so I thought it might work to move the whitespace into the optional group, like this:

`-> (.+)( \(cost=([\d\.]+) rows=(\d+)\))? \(actual time=([\d\.]+) rows=(\d+) loops=(\d+)\)`

Which did not work.

It seems to match the optional group *as part* of the first group, which is not really what I want. I want them separate, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know it might look a bit confusing, but the first group is really just info about a specific query operation and not all that relevant. It could very well have been "Nested loop inner join" instead of "Single-row index lookup on using <auto_distinct_key> (actor_id=actor.actor_id)" as in this case.

Comment: So, you want to retrieve: `Single-row index lookup on using <auto_distinct_key> (actor_id=actor.actor_id)`. Than optionally `901.66` and `5478` . And `0.001..0.001`, `0`, `200` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the first `(.+)` lazy quantifier `(.+?)`
https://regex101.com/r/fbE0tW/1

```
 # (.+?)[ ]?((?<=[ ])\(cost=([\d\.]+)[ ]rows=(\d+)\))?[ ]\(actual[ ]time=([\d\.]+)[ ]rows=(\d+)[ ]loops=(\d+)\)
 
 ( .+? )                       # (1)
 [ ]? 
 (                             # (2 start)
    (?<= [ ] )
    \( cost=
    ( [\d\.]+ )                   # (3)
    [ ] rows=
    ( \d+ )                       # (4)
    \) 
 )?                            # (2 end)
 [ ] 
 \( 
 actual [ ] time=
 ( [\d\.]+ )                   # (5)
 [ ] 
 rows=
 ( \d+ )                       # (6)
 [ ] 
 loops=
 ( \d+ )                       # (7)
 \)
```

Comment: "You have to make the first (.+) lazy quantifier (.+?)" 

Thank you, that solved the problem. Much appreciated.